# What is the best Captcha plugin for registration?

Tags: captcha

I'm suffering from the issue of lots of fake registrations for my site.
I'd like to add a captcha for registrations.  What is the best plugin that
will require a captcha at registration?  Recommendations based on real installs are most appriciated!

Also: I'm using the most up-to-date install of WP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My favorite captcha plugin is [reCaptcha](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/wordpress.html). The captcha images are scans from old, damaged books. A computer identifies possibilities with OCR, then the user, in correctly filling out the captcha, confirms it. It helps digitize whole books this way.

It's an initiative by Google. Read about them [on their website](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/whyrecaptcha).

Comment: isn't this a captcha for comments only? I didn't see registration mentioned

Comment: @Lea, it seems so. Here's a version cooked up by someone which works for registration. Sorry about that.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-recaptcha/

Answer (score 5):

## Update:   From my hard-earned and painful expereince, [KeyCAPTCHA is a scam by professional spammers](http://keycaptchaured.wordpress.com)

---

[keycaptcha.com](https://www.keycaptcha.com/) site has live online demo and it serves not only WordPress/BuddyPress powered websites but all PHP5-based CMSs.  It is specially designed that in case of being cracked, pool of captchas and even its type (of interactivity for passing) can be changed without plugin reinstall

Other unique features worth to mention:

- Customizable language support. It supports a dozen of languages (including German) and requests for new ones are welcome
- One can [create his own captchas from his own images with online designer (fee-based servce in addition to free of charge one - $5/month, $20/year)](https://www.keycaptcha.com/whatisit/?s=pc)

SI Captcha and reCAPTCHA ([recommended in one of answers in this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12989/what-is-the-best-captcha-plugin-for-registration/12992#12992)) are easily passable by spam bots

Comment: Unfortunately, this plugin is totally inaccessible.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 4):

**I actually recommend not using a traditional captcha at all.**

Many usability studies show that complex or image based captchas reduce sign ups by a whopping 25-60% depending on complexity.

The alternatives are:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/registrap/

Using simple math question
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/block-spam-by-math/

Personally I use  1 hidden field and it works like a charm and no need to squint and some lame image.

Comment: I rejected edit by Pwn of this answer since I don't feel answer edits are appropriate discussion technique (comments are). But he had (seemingly) valid point that plugins in this answer mostly relate to comments spam, while original question is about registration spam.

Comment: **PS** I've opened topic on meta [Are low-rep edits inappropriate as discussional tool?](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/517/are-low-rep-edits-inappropriate-as-discussional-tool) to check if my decision was correct.

Comment: I went ahead and deleted the plugins I listed, I read the OP wrong, sorry, still an applicable idea though.

Comment: Agree that captcha is a poor solution - take a look at this post http://www.90percentofeverything.com/2011/03/25/fk-captcha/

Answer (score 3):

That depends. Do you have a custom registration page in your template, or are you using the default WordPress registration page? Or the Buddypress registration page maybe?

Have a look at SI Captcha as it supports both. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/si-captcha-for-wordpress/

OR if you want a cleaner looking captcha try WP-Recaptcha (API key required- free) http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-recaptcha/

I've used both and haven't had any spam sign ups yet! ... as further security you could install ban-hammer and enable stopforumspam feature that auto-blocks any e-mails on the blacklist from registering!! (do a google search for wordpress banhammer plugin... i'd link you but it won't let me post more than 2 links)

Answer (score 2):

i like SweetCaptcha.com , they have Wordpress and Joomla plugins 
here is the wordpress:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sweetcaptcha-revolutionary-free-captcha-service/

Answer (score 1):

The one plugin all my clients love (for unknown reason) is [KeyCAPTCHA - Free interactive CAPTCHA service](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/keycaptcha/) (that is the real name).
I like it because it integrates with  :

- Registration form
- Comment form
- Login form
- Lost password form
- Contact Form 7
- BuddyPress

Answer (score -1):

Cartpauj Register Captcha works very well for me: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cartpauj-register-captcha/